# Take a column and convert value to int

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

```
public int AuthenticatedUserAge(String User_name)
{
    string sql = "SELECT UserName,Age FROM tblDataProg WHERE (UserName ='" + User_name + "')";
    ds = GetDataSet(sql);

    int help = int.Parse(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Age"].ToString());

    return help;
}
```

I can't figure why this line doesn't convert the age to type int and return a value:

```
int help = int.Parse(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Age"].ToString());
```

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: Have you checked to see what value is returned by `ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Age"].ToString()`? Debug it, and see if it's a valid number, no spaces or special characters.

Comment: I GET AN ERROR : Input string was not in a correct format.  the age value is taken from the table data it is valid and the age is int for sure @Tdorno

Comment: Maybe no user name matches the name you are putting in, so there is no data.

Comment: i take the user name from my session @GordonLinoff

Comment: here is my full code i possted it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23724273/take-a-column-and-convert-value-to-int?noredirect=1#comment36464809_23724273

Comment: Before you parse it put a break point or quick watch and see the value of `ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Age"]`. To my doubt it's empty.

Answer (score 1):

Completely offtopic to the question, but I think it's worth mentioning. Please don't create your SQL statements by concatenating strings. This creates [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attack possibility. Instead consider [SqlParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx) class and compose your WHERE predicates using such parameters.

Here you get [nice example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (look especially at convenient AddWithValue method).

Thanks!

Comment: Not off topic really, and a point worth noting if you don't already know this.

Answer (score 0):

Test your assumptions more. You are assuming GetDataSet is returning a row but it possibly isn't: -

```
int help = 0;

if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
{
    throw new ApplicationException("no rows were returned, here is an error to deal with");
}
else if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Age"] == System.DbNull.Value)
{
    throw new ApplicationException("a row was found but Age is null, here is an error to deal with");
}
else
{
    help = int.Parse(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Age"].ToString());
}
```

Comment: unfurtenatly i tried this but like i thought the value is not the problem i checkd it and i get an alert that the help=int.parse..... is the problem i printed the value that is returnd and changed the code line to:                          int.TryParse(Convert.ToString(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Age"]),out help);   and know it does print me a value but it prints my : 0 when the age is 27  @sh1rts

Comment: So you mean to say - age is 27, and you've confirmed this by examining the value of ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Age"] at runtime -but when you int.Parse or int.TryParse this, it returns 0 ?

Answer (score 0):

try

int help;

int.TryParse(Convert.ToString(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Age"]),out help);

and see the code in debug mode

Comment: i printed the value that is returnd and changed the code line to: int.TryParse(Convert.ToString(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Age"]),out help); and know it does print me a value but it prints my : 0 when the age is 27 thank you for your help :) @linodh

Comment: Just check the value in debug mode   (use immediate window) for ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Age"] is 27 or null or empty